# Perl warning: Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string

Tags: regex, perl

I cannot figure out why the regex patterns are not matching. Also, the output complains that `$found` is not initialized, but I believe I did so. Here is my code so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @strange_list = ('hungry_elephant', 'dancing_dinosaur');

my $regex_patterns = qr/
    elephant$
    ^dancing
    /x;

foreach my $item (@strange_list) {
    my ($found) = $item =~ m/($regex_patterns)/i;
    print "Found: $found\n";
}
```

Here is the output I get:

```
Use of uninitialized value $found in concatenation (.) or string at C:\scripts\perl\sandbox\regex.pl line 13.
Found:
Use of uninitialized value $found in concatenation (.) or string at C:\scripts\perl\sandbox\regex.pl line 13.
Found:
```

Do I need to initialize `$found` in another manner? Also, am I correctly creating a multi-line string to be interpreted as regex?

Many thanks.

Comment: your multiline string is being interpreted as `qr/elephant$^dancing/;` whereas you probably want `qr/elephant$|^dancing/;`

Comment: For multi-line matching, use the /m switch: `my $regex_patterns = qr/elephant$^dancing/mx;`

Comment: sometimes its better just to turn off this warnings. Add this to your perl header - no warnings 'uninitialized'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the pattern match (`=~`) doesn't match anything, nothing will be stored in your scalar `$found` so Perl is complaining that you are trying to interpolate a variable that wasn't given a value.

You can get around this easily by using the postfix unless conditional:

```
$found = "Nothing" unless $found
print "Found: $found\n";
```

The code above assigns the value "Nothing" to `$found` *only* if it does not already have a value. Now your print statement will always work correctly, in either case.

You could also just use a simple if statement, but that seems more verbose:

```
if( $found ) {
   print "Found: $found\n";
}
else {
   print "Not found\n";
}
```

Another option that might be the most clean, is to place your pattern match in the if statement:

```
if( my ($found) = $item =~ m/($regex_patterns)/i ) {
   # if here, you know for sure that there was a match
   print "Found: $found\n";
}
```

Comment: Could you please show an example of how I can add my regex to your line containing "unless"?

Comment: @DirtyPenguin Your regex would be on the line *before* that line.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is missing a separator. Insert `|` between the elephant and dancing.

Moreover, you should print `Found` only if anything was really found. You can fix that by

```
print "Found: $found\n" if defined $found;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Double forward slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873379/what-does-the-double-forward-slash-mean-here) (`//`) can also be used to initialize `$found`. It is very similar to `unless`. The only thing to do is modifying the `print` line as follows.

```
print "Found: " . ($found // 'Nothing') . "\n";
```

If `$found` is uninitialized, 'Nothing' will be printed.

The outcome (Perl v5.10.1):

```
Found: Nothing
Found: Nothing
```