# what does the double forward slash mean here?

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and came across this piece of code at work, I search for a while but did not find the answer. Can anyone help to explain its function in plain english? thanks.

```
my $abc = delete $args{ 'abc' } // croak 'some information!';
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From this page here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or

> Although it has no direct equivalent in C, Perl's `//` operator is related to its C-style `or`. In fact, it's exactly the same as `||`, except that it tests the left hand side's **definedness** instead of its **truth**. Thus, `EXPR1 // EXPR2` returns the value of `EXPR1` if it's defined, otherwise, the value of `EXPR2` is returned. (`EXPR1` is evaluated in *scalar* context, `EXPR2` in the context of `//` itself). Usually, this is the same result as `defined(EXPR1) ? EXPR1 : EXPR2` (except that the ternary-operator form can be used as a lvalue, while `EXPR1 // EXPR2` cannot, and EXPR1 will only be evaluated once). This is very useful for providing default values for variables. If you actually want to test if at least one of `$a` and `$b` is defined, use `defined($a // $b)`.

Comment: This is similar to SQL's COALESCE function (although only two operands are supported here)

Answer (score 11):

Check for [Logical Defined-Or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) in perlop, it is similar to `||` but it checks for `undef` value (not false one).

> Although it has no direct equivalent in C, Perl's // operator is related to its C-style or. In fact, it's exactly the same as ||, except that it tests the left hand side's definedness instead of its truth.

So in short,

```
my $abc = delete $args{ 'abc' } // croak 'some information!';
```

will croak when `$args{ 'abc' }` returns `undef` value.