# Unexpected results from ifelse

Tags: r

I am getting unexpected results from the  `ifelse` function :

```
vector <- factor(c('x', 'x', 'y', 'z'), levels = c('x', 'y', 'z'))
ifelse(class(vector) == "factor", yes = levels(vector), no =
unique(vector)) # Returns character "x" and not the expected c("x", "y",
"z")

# Manual debug
class(vector) == "factor" # TRUE
levels(vector) # [1] "x" "y" "z"
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: You need `if`, i.e. `if(is.factor(vector)){levels(vector)}else{unique(vector)}`

Comment: from `?ifelse` we can learn that the value returned by it is *A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and "class") as test and data values from the values of yes or no*

Comment: An overkill option: borrow `//` from perl and do something like `levels(x) // unique(x)`... in practice: `\`%//%\` = function(x,y) if (!is.null(x)) x else y; levels(x) %//% unique(x)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873379/what-does-the-double-forward-slash-mean-here

Comment: Another slightly overkill option, but with `ifelse` is: `unlist(ifelse(class(vector) == "factor", list((levels(vector))), list(unique(vector))))`. You change`ifelse` to return a list with one element and then you `unlist` that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just want to use an `if` statement. Not `ifelse()`. The latter is meant to work with vectors and return a vector with length equal to that of the input. if you want to return a different number of elements for different conditions, just use `if`.

```
vector <- factor(c('x', 'x', 'y', 'z'), levels = c('x', 'y', 'z'))
xx <- if(class(vector) == "factor") levels(vector) else unique(vector)
xx
```