# R: ifelse statement on dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c("A","B","C"), y2 = c(1, 2, 3), y3 = c(4, 5, 6))
```

I want to make all values < 3 to zero.

I did this:

```
d2 <- ifelse(d1[,2:3] > 3,  d1[,2:3], 0)
```

However, it returns me a list. I need the exact dataframe but with values < 3 as zeros.

Comment: Don't use `ifelse`. Just do `d1[d1[2:3] < 3, 2:3] <- 0`

Comment: `ifelse` should be used on atomic vectors, not a whole data.frame. David's comment is spot on but you could also loop over the columns of your data.frame with `lapply` and run an `ifelse` to each column (a vector).

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47816693/unexpected-results-from-ifelse

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
d1[, 2:3] <- lapply(d1[, 2:3], function(x) ifelse(x < 3, 0, x))

> d1
  y1 y2 y3
1  A  0  4
2  B  0  5
3  C  3  6
```