# Error while using ifelse in apply function - R

Tags: r, if-statement

Hello I have the following code;

```
valorNegativos = function (vela) {
  for(a in 1:length(vela)) {
    apply(vela[[a]], 2,  function(col) ifelse( length(as.numeric(col) < 0) == length(vela[[a]]$FECHA), print(paste0("Correct data")), stop("ERROR: Negative values"))
  }
}
```

vela, is a list of dataframes.

What I have to do with this function is to prove if all the columns values from all my dataframes are positive ( > 0 ) and to check if the number of values is equal to the value count from one column $FECHA ( date ).

The problem is that I am getting the two posibilites from the ifelse.

```
[1] "Correct data"
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in ifelse(length(as.numeric(col) > 0) == length(vela[[a]]$FECHA,  : 
  ERROR: Negative values
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(vela)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(vela, 20))`.

Comment: Looks to me like you're asking the function to `stop` anytime `length(as.numeric(col) < 0) != length(vela[[a]]$FECHA)`. The error you're getting is from your function.

Comment: You can check the entire data frame for positive values with something like this, `sum(mtcars>0)/(nrow(mtcars)*ncol(mtcars))`

Comment: You should be very, very careful when using ifelse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47816693/unexpected-results-from-ifelse

Comment: use `ifelse` for vectorized operations only, in you case use `if (...) ... else ...`

Comment: Thanks, I think is a problem about I lost ")", here is my code working properly.

Comment: for(a in 1:length(vela)) {
    apply(vela[[a]], 2,  function(col) ifelse( suppressWarnings(length(as.numeric(col) < 0)) == length(vela[[a]]$FECHA), print(paste0("Datos correctos" )), stop("ERROR: Existen datos negativos")))
  }